# Webpages cannot be displayed / Domain names are not being resolved

Tags: dns

This problem has been bugging me since last time I reinstall my system (about 20 days ago).

Most of the time when I try to open a website (ANY), it doesn't load, simply and instantly "cannot display the webpage", IE8/FF4/Chrome12/Opera11/Safari5. So I believe it's not the browser.

When this happens, I have to ping the domain to get the IP, and the IP always works fine. OR, I have to keep pressing F5 to refresh, maybe 20, 30 times, it'll work. But this is really painful.

I can make sure my internet is connected 24/7 because my download accelerator can work forever (>200KB all the time).

So the only thing left is DNS I guess, domain names are just not being resolved on my computer.

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered the same problem and come up with a working soluion.

OS: Win XP SP2 x64
DNS Client Service: Disabled (for Kaspersky, but even if it's enabled the problem lies there)
Router: TL-WR840N with default settings

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a virus to me... I'd wipe and reinstall to be safe. However, this question probably doesn't belong here. Stackoverflow is for programming related questions. I don't particularly care, but others might give you a hassle.

- Jeff

Comment: Ooops...sorry if I'v made anyone uncomfortable asking this question here. It won't happen again. Regarding the problem, I can be 99% sure I'm not virus infected...